# Delete the contents of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `users` with this

[image]

What is the correct query for delete ONLY the data in field `telephone`?

Comment: What do you mean by deleting the data? Do you want to remove the column entirely, or just set the values to NULL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE USERS SET TELEPHONE = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't delete the data per se, just perform an UPDATE like so:

```
UPDATE users set telephone = 0
```

Edit to consider INT field.  Answered elsewhere in any case.

Comment: telephone is an int